# How to apply CSS Style to QMenu via an entire MainWIndow

Tags: python, css, qt, pyqt, stylesheet

Running the example code below creates a single button window. Clicking up the button brings up a pull-down menu.

[image]

When CSS 'appStyle' is applied to `menu` directly it seems to be working well:

```
menu.setStyleSheet(appStyle)
```

But when the same CSS 'appStyle' is assigned to the entire window using:

```
view.setStyleSheet(appStyle)
```

nothing happens (just comment out the `menu.setStyleSheet(appStyle)` to see it).
It would be great if the CSS stylesheet would be once for an entire view and not for each menu or every widget separately. How to achieve it?

```
bgColor='#1F1F1F'
appStyle="""
QMenu {{  font-size:10pt; selection-background-color: #ffaa00; selection-color: black; background-color: #7A7A7A; border-style: solid; border: 0px solid #EBEBEB; border-radius: 0; color: #EBEBEB; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }}
QMenu:on  {{padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; background-color: #7A7A7A; selection-background-color: #ffaa00; color: #EBEBEB; border-radius: 0;}}
QMenu QAbstractItemView  {{ border: 0px solid black; background-color: #7A7A7A; color: #EBEBEB; border-radius: 0; }}
QMenu:hover {{ border: 0px solid #ffa02f; }}
QMenu::drop-down  {{ border-radius: 0px; background-color: #7A7A7A; color: #EBEBEB; }}""".format(bgColor) 


from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__() 
        button=QToolButton(self)
        button.setText('Click Here')

        menu=QMenu()
        menu.addAction("Action01")
        menu.addAction("Action02")
        menu.addAction("Action03")

        separator=menu.addAction("")
        separator.setSeparator(True)

        subMenu=menu.addMenu('SubMenu')
        subMenu.addAction("SubAction01")
        subMenu.addAction("SubAction02")
        subMenu.addAction("SubAction03")   

        button.setMenu(menu)
        button.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)
        menu.setStyleSheet(appStyle)   


app=QApplication(sys.argv)    
view=Window() 
view.setStyleSheet(appStyle)
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass an instance of view `self` on `QMenu` declaration.
So, instead of:

```
menu=QMenu()
```

do:

```
menu=QMenu(self)
```

Now when a stylesheet is applied to a main window its stylesheet is propagated down its children - a `menu` and `button` instances in this case.

[image]

The working code is below:

```
bgColor='#1F1F1F'
appStyle="""
QToolButton {{border: 0px solid #0F0F0F; background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #7A7A7A, stop: 1 #0F0F0F); color: #EBEBEB}}
QMenu QAbstractItemView  {{ border: 0px solid black; background-color: #7A7A7A; color: #EBEBEB; border-radius: 0; }}
QMenu {{  font-size:10pt; selection-background-color: #ffaa00; selection-color: black; background-color: #7A7A7A; border-style: solid; border: 0px solid #EBEBEB; border-radius: 0; color: #EBEBEB; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }}
QMenu:on  {{padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; background-color: #7A7A7A; selection-background-color: #ffaa00; color: #EBEBEB; border-radius: 0;}}
QMenu:hover {{ border: 0px solid #ffa02f; }}
QMenu::drop-down  {{ border-radius: 0px; background-color: #7A7A7A; color: #EBEBEB; }}""".format(bgColor) 

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__() 
        button=QToolButton(self)
        button.setText('Click Here')

        menu=QMenu(self)
        menu.addAction("Action01")
        menu.addAction("Action02")
        menu.addAction("Action03")

        separator=menu.addAction("")
        separator.setSeparator(True)

        subMenu=menu.addMenu('SubMenu')
        subMenu.addAction("SubAction01")
        subMenu.addAction("SubAction02")
        subMenu.addAction("SubAction03")   

        button.setMenu(menu)
        button.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
view=Window() 
view.setStyleSheet(appStyle)
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```